# Rails POST doesnt extract any path, query or request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to grant users access to my API (hosted on heroku.com) from their sites.
But a strange problem occurs, when i want them to allow to post to the api:

Data sent from an correct form with the correct action-url (e.g. "http://myapp.com/projects/123/tasks/321/todos") - the params get serialized and send via jQuery - i encounter an "ActionController::MethodNotAllowed" with the additional info: "Only get and post requests are allowed", that re-routes to ApplicationController#index with :method => :options.

Rails doesnt extract the params for project_id (123) and task_id (321) from the url, neither are any further request_parameters, path_parameters or query_parameters available.

This behaviour occurs, when I POST from external sites, but doesn't occur, when posting from an html-page on my local machine. My first thought was about wrong encoding, but how to fix that problem.

Edit:
I am using authlogic (not devise :-D) and for the :create action the protect_from_forgery is already skipped.

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured due to the cross domain policy - the request was made from another domain - and because I was using a recent browser that supports [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/), it was sending an OPTIONS-request first to get known from the server, which actions are allowed for this domain.

Answer (score 0):

i guess that happens because rails tries to protect your form CSRF attacks.

you can comment out the `protect_from_forgery` line in your ApplicationController to test it.

but im not sure if thats the right way of dealing with this issue in the production environment.

Comment: I edited my post, so that is clear now, that for the create the protect_from_forgery is already skipped - thx for your suggestion anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I'll try and answer the right question this time (see other comment).

So I've thought about this, and I'm wondering, is this a case of the jQuery call attempting a PUT request? When you use the local form Rails will POST the data, but add the extra `_method` field to emulate a PUT.

Don't know if you are using [jquery-rails](https://github.com/robertsosinski/jquery-rails), but this takes care of setting the _method parameter, and the PUT/POST verb translation for you in your AJAX calls.